# How to handle an item being apart of multiple lists in Elasticsearch?

Tags: database-design, elasticsearch

I'm working on a system where a document indexed by Elasticsearch can show up in multiple lists.

List names:

- LIST1
- LIST2
- LIST3
- LIST4

Document being indexed:

```
{ title : 'Title' }
```

I receive documents like this once a second. A document can appear in several lists (some business logic determines which lists the document belongs too). My current approach is to append the list data to the document so the document looks something like this:

```
{ title : 'Title', lists : ['LIST2', 'LIST4'] }
```

This approach enables me to list all documents in LIST2 by simply querying documents where the lists array contains LIST2. It also enables me to search for documents in LIST2.

A new requirement came down from the client that the LISTS need to be mergable. That means a user can merge LIST3 into LIST2, which essentially means:

- Updates all documents that have the LIST3 list attached and change it to LIST2
- Delete LIST2.

**My question:** Is there a better way to handle this in Elasticsearch? How scalable is this approach? The problem areas in my opinion may be:

1. A lot of LISTS in the future (could be a million). The more LISTS a post is a part of, the bigger the documents lists array will be. How well does Elasticsearch do in this department?
2. Merging lists seems to be a very expensive operation.

Comment: A sample document (json) will be more helpful.

Comment: I've got a bunch more fields, but I've stripped them out. Here's a slightly less simplified version of the document: https://gist.github.com/peeter-tomberg/b285f900095cd89563bf watchlists is the array of lists (mongo IDs) the document is in.

Comment: And, how the merging is said to occour,? in your document?

Comment: Currently we do it "manually". We query all documents that contain LIST3 in "lists" and update all of them to include LIST2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can index the list objects as their own types, where the list itself for example just has a list of document IDs that belong to that list.  Then when you need to query documents based on which list(s) the documents belong to, you can use the terms lookup filter  (a "join" of sorts)- http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/terms-filter-lookup/.

There is no need to do two separate queries -- term lookups are built into elasticsearch to do exactly the kind of query that requires checking membership via a different document type (i.e. a "lookup" -- exactly like a join or a "where in").  Not only do you not need to do two separate queries, but there is also caching on the elasticsearch side that makes this quite performant.

This makes it easier to manage list membership because you only need to update ONE document (the list document) to merge lists, but you can still query the information as needed when searching for specific documents based on list membership.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer really depends on what you're willing to give up in exchange for greater flexibility. Your solution definitely has advantages at query time, but perhaps you don't want to spend so many resources re-indexing all the changes? If so, the other solution here suggests maintaining a separate type that stores the relationship in reverse, where the index is list based, and you can update your list much more easily.

One pitfall of this might be losing flexibility at search time. If you want details of each document in list 'A', you'd have to query 'list' type, and then run another query against all the docID's for that list. There might be plugins to allow you to join your query (using this specific architecture), but you'll have to do some research.

Also, this could get problematic if your list ends up getting really big (imagine indexing a list document with a million titles!). But then again, you could run into similar issues in your solution if you have to update a million documents with the correct list of listIDs. It comes down to your expectation of how big your data set will eventually become, and which features are most important to you when applying the solution.

Having said that, another potential solution could be using parent/child documents. The parent would be the list, and the children would be the documents. This would keep query flexibility intact, since you can query for child documents against discriminators on the parent. But how would merges work? As mentioned, there is a cost to everything, and in this case, I would design the list so that it has 2 ID fields. One would hold the 'previous' list name, and another would be the searchable alias.

For instance, you have list 'A' and list 'B'. The basic document structure would be something like list : { alias: 'A', name: 'A'}, and likewise for B. Say some day, you want to merge A into B. What you would do then, is update List document A, and set the alias of 'A' as 'B'. At search time, when searching for documents, you will query look something like 'where parent.alias = [list_name]'. Also, for purposes of audit, you could queue up the list name that just got replaced ('A') into the previous list name field. (This part is totally optional.. up to how you want to do it)

Unfortunately, this would mean you can have MANY list types with the same alias (and also takes up more mem), but this prevents massive re-indexing (on either scale), and you take a small performance hit at search time to support the parent/child relationship (the docs will share the same shard at search time, but not sharing the same segments like with nested documents).